# Evaluate math formula from String using ScriptEngine

Tags: java, string

Here is my code:

```
double value = 2.55;
String formule = "x+x";
```

and I want to replace x variable in sentence to `value` variable, so my next code is:

```
formule = formule.replace("x", String.valueOf(value));
System.out.println(formule);
```

and I have `0.0+0.0` returned in terminal.

---

Here is my code where x -> 0.0 forever:

```
protected double Formule(Double Value) throws ScriptException
{
    String ValueString = Value.toString();
    ScriptEngineManager factory = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine engine = factory.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
    Double source = null;
    formule = formule.replace("sin", "Math.sin").
         replace("cos", "Math.cos").
         replace("tan", "Math.tan").
         replace("sqrt", "Math.sqrt").
         replace("sqr", "Math.pow").
         replace("log", "Math.log").
         replace("x", ValueString);
    try {
        source = (Double)engine.eval(formule);
    } catch(Exception exc) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid input", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
    this.repaint();
    return source;
}
```

**Resolved!!!**

i just created temporary string named `tmp` and now its looks like this

```
protected double Formule(Double Value) throws ScriptException
{       
    String tmp;
    tmp = formule.replace("sin", "Math.sin").
    replace("cos", "Math.cos").
    replace("tan", "Math.tan").
    replace("sqrt", "Math.sqrt").
    replace("sqr", "Math.pow").
    replace("log", "Math.log").
    replace("x", String.valueOf(Value));
    try {
        return (Double)engine.eval(tmp);
    } catch(Exception fexp) {
        return null;      
    }
    return 0;
}
```

because `String formule` is global variable in my class

Comment: What is wrong, except the obvious typo "replase"?

Comment: @DanielB OP wants/needs to use a formula evalulator using a basic `String` for it. That's not wrong at all, so I don't know why this question is receiving so many downvotes.

Comment: In my code nothing wrong, only here, in this post

Comment: Then you understood something I didn't. No downvote from me though..

Comment: If your problem is how to evaluate a formula from a `String`, then this won't do since you need a formula evaluation library or use a JavaScript Engine and evaluate this formula like a JavaScript code, otherwise, the code should compile and run as expected.

Comment: Added the code from your deleted answer. Next time, please edit your question and add the relevant information instead of posting an answer.

Comment: -1 Nobody knows what you actually want the code to do, so it is impossible to understand what it is doing wrong.

Comment: @BaileyS I've edited the question title. Do you now understand the question?

Comment: It would help to know the value of `String formule` before and after the `replace`s call.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code (from your post) -

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  double value = 2.55;
  String formule = "x+x";
  formule = formule.replace("x",
      String.valueOf(value));
  System.out.println(formule);
}
```

prints

```
2.55+2.55
```

when run here. Are you sure you're accessing the same `double value` you initialized above? It looks like you must be accessing another variable (which is not initialized as expected - so has the value `0`) named `value`.

Comment: that's a relief, I was really wondering what was wrong in the question's code!

Comment: After your edit: *It looks like you must be accessing another variable (which is not initialized) named value* the variable should be initialized with a value of `0`, otherwise the code would not even compile...

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza `Double value;` perhaps... who knows?

Comment: That's variable declaration, not initialization. Local uninitialized variables cannot be used unless you set a value on them, they're not initialized with a default value like class fields.